# When is it appropriate to use C++ exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception, memory, error-handling, raii

I'm trying to design a class that needs to dynamically allocate some memory..

I had planned to allocate the memory it needs during construction, but how do I handle failed memory allocations? Should I throw an exception? I read somewhere that exceptions should only be used for "exceptional" cases, and running out of memory doesn't seem like an exceptional case to me..

Should I allocate memory in a separate initialization routine instead and check for failures and then destroy the class instance gracefully?

Or should I use exceptions instead?  The class won't have anything useful to do if these memory allocations should fail..

---

EDIT: The consensus seems to be that running out of memory IS an exceptional case.

Will see how to go about this.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you are using new to allocate memory, and are not overriding the `new` operator, it will automatically throw the `std::bad_alloc` exception if it fails to allocate memory properly.

> I read somewhere that exceptions
>   should only be used for "exceptional"
>   cases, and running out of memory
>   doesn't seem like an exceptional case
>   to me..

Running out of memory seems like a pretty exceptional case to me :)

It is very difficult to handle this sort of situation.  You may want to return a meaningful error to the user of your application, but if it's a problem caused by lack of memory, you may not even be able to afford the memory to allocate the error message.  It's a bit of a catch-22 situation really.

There is a defensive programming technique (sometimes called a memory parachute or rainy day fund) where you allocate a chunk of memory when your application starts.  When you then handle the `bad_alloc` exception, you free this memory up, and use the available memory to close down the application gracefully, including displaying a meaningful error to the user.  This is much better than crashing :)

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that running out of memory (particularly heap memory) is an exceptional case, and if your class - and further, your application - cannot continue, I think exception throwing/handling is a very appropriate and graceful approach.

Answer (score 1):

The usual behaviour in C++ when you are out of memory is to throw an exception.  The built-in `new` operator does this by default.